# CSS div has NaN dimensions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to finalize on of the pages that I am fixing for a client, and it seems that one of the div's within the page that I am attempting to add padding to won't work for vertical padding. I checked the element using chrome's dev tools, and it stated the element had "NaN x NaN" for dimensions.

[image]

The element is clearly being displayed, but I cannot add padding to it as a result. To see what I am talking about, [click here](http://1rogue.com/shopfine/3cart.html#cart-acc) and look at `.accordion-heading > .accordion-toggle`. It's a bit frustrating because it's preventing me from finishing this tiny bit of the page. How can an element have supposedly no dimensions, and how can I fix it? I've tried adding manual width and height, to no avail.

Comment: IE displays its dimensions as *auto* × *auto*: http://hypftier.de/temp/2013-10-12_171146.png. I guess *NaN* is another way of saying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because it's an `inline` element. Change its display to `inline-block` and you'll be able to add padding.

```css
a.accordion-toggle {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea as to why it would cause the "NaN" dimensions though?

Comment: Dimensions of inline elements are entirely controlled by the content within them. It could be said that inline elements technically don't have dimensions of their own at all. If you fancy reading into the difference between inline-level and block-level containers you can check out this section of the CSS2.1 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch again, this saved me quite a bit of an annoying css headache.